# Play audio and restart it onclick

Tags: javascript, html, audio, onclick

I'm looking to restart an audio file in a HTML5 audio player. I have defined a audio file and a `play` button.

```
<audio id="audio1" src="01.wav"></audio>
<button onClick="play()">Play</button>
```

When I click the `play` button the audio file starts playing, but when I click the button again the audio file doesn't stop and will not play again until it reaches the end of the file.

```
function play() {
    document.getElementById('audio1').play();
}
```

Is there a method that would allow me to restart the audio file when I click the button using `onclick` rather than waiting for the song to stop?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

To just restart the song, you'd do:

```
function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio1');
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    }else{
        audio.currentTime = 0
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/s42hb/1/)

To toggle it, as in the audio stops when clicking again, and when click another time it restarts from the beginning, you'd do something more like :

```
function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio1');
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    }else{
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/s42hb/2/)

Comment: But what if you are working with multiple files and/or buttons?

Answer (score 1):

```
soundManager.setup({
preferFlash: false,
//, url: "swf/"
onready: function () {
    soundManager.createSound({
        url: [
            "http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.mp3", "http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.ogg"
        ],
        id: "music"
    });
    soundManager.createSound({
        url: [
            "http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3", 
        ],
        id: "horse"
    });
    soundManager.play("music"); 
}
```

}).beginDelayedInit();

And to start horse and pause all other sounds currently playing in a click event:

```
$("#horse").click(function () {
soundManager.stopAll();
soundManager.play("horse");
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
function sound(src) {
    this.sound = document.createElement("audio");
    this.sound.src = src;
    this.sound.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
    this.sound.setAttribute("controls", "none");
    //this.sound.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(this.sound);
    this.play = function () {
        this.sound.play();
    }
    this.stop = function () {
        this.sound.pause();
        this.sound.currentTime = 0
    }
}
```

you can use the /above function to play sound

```
 let mysound1 = new sound('xyz.mp3')
 mysound1.play()
```